# ggplot: Barplot with more than one grouping variables and adjusting the colours for the grouping variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a barplot (stacked perhaps?) that is similar to either of the following two plots in R with ggplot:

1/ [image]

2/ [image]

I would prefer to make a barplot similar to the second plot but to make one similar to the first one would do too.

Here is my sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  year = c(1988,1989,1990,1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1996,1997,
           1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,
           2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,
           2018,2019,2020,2021,2022),
  LS4 = c(0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
          0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
          0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
          0,0,0,0,0),
  LS5 = c(35,45,37,29,23,32,46,35,47,40,
          52,55,46,38,0,6,47,41,45,43,
          42,49,29,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,
          0,0,0,0,0),
  LS7 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
          0,3,20,24,43,33,42,27,25,26,
          26,38,23,23,28,34,50,56,49,52,
          51,57,54,48,49),
  LS8 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
          0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
          0,0,0,0,0,33,60,61,58,53,
          58,60,55,53,49),
  LS9 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
          0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
          0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
          0,0,0,6,52),
  obs = c(35,50,37,29,23,32,46,35,47,40,
          52,58,66,62,43,39,89,68,70,69,
          68,87,52,48,28,67,110,117,107,105,
          109,117,109,107,150))
```

I have tried the following to create barplot

```
barplot1 <- data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=year, y=obs, fill=interaction(LS4,LS5,LS7,LS8,LS9))) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "cyan", "red", "orange"))
barplot1
```

And the result looks like this

[image]

Could someone please help me with this question :) I really appreaciate it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could convert your data to a longer format using `pivot_longer` and assign the names to `fill` with its values. You could use `geom_col` to create the stacked bars. If you want to color your bars you should use `scale_fill_manual` since you use `fill` in the aesthetics to color bars like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = LS4:LS9) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=year, y=value, fill=name)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "cyan", "red", "orange", "yellow"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Wow thank you so much for the quick answer, this is a pretty neat trick that I didn't know of :)

Comment: Do you happen to know how to make the plot similar to my second example plot at the beginning of the post as well @Quinten?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a similar alternative:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

# color LS
ls_colors <- c("gold", "red", "steelblue", "orange", "purple")

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(year, obs)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(year, value, fill = name)) +
  geom_col(position = position_stack()) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = ls_colors) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @TarJae !

Do you also happen to know how to make the plot similar to my second example plot at the beginning of the post as well @Quinten?